# C#: async method for controlling network crashes after detachment network

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, service, ping

I'm doing an async method that service broker through me notification if the client is connected with the server .
The problem is that the method works perfectly, but when I do the backup , test the connection to disconnect the network cable , and piecing ... and here lies the problem : Every time I do a while and is connected the network cable that is connected properly marked me , but as soon as I disconnect the network cable I debugging stops me off debugging . Not why but detaching the cable , hangs around , and does not go more , I tested with the try catch , but no exception , simply stops the while, and the method is to vegetate in anything .
Can someone explain how to solve , or at least , why ? Thank you.

```
private static async Task checkEnrollmentAsync()
{
    dataaccess da = new dataaccess();

    using (var webapiclient = new HttpClient())
    {
        webapiclient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myaddressforcheckOnlineService/");
        webapiclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        webapiclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // HTTP GET

        while (true)
        {
            //bool networkUp = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
            bool networkUp = IsAvailableNetworkActive();
            if (networkUp)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10000); //300000+
                HttpResponseMessage response = await webapiclient.GetAsync("api/myaddressforcheckOnlineService");
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await da._checkEnrollmentConnection(true);
                    log.Info("enrollment OK, scrittura su db connessione ok");
                }
                else
                {
                    await da._checkEnrollmentConnection(false);
                    log.Error("enrollment KO");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await da._checkEnrollmentConnection(false);
                log.Error("enrollment KO");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code is in a windows service.